# How to ResolveAll the instances of a type in IContainerProvider (prism 7+)

Tags: wpf, prism

I have multiple implementations of an interface registered as services in the unity container. Till Prim 5 the UnityBootstrapper is doing its job well. I am able to ResolveAll instances of the service and choose which one to use further among them.

From Prism 7 onward, I couldn't find a way to ResolveAll the instances of the type via the IContainerProvider. Any ideas?

cc: prism devs

Answer (score 2):

Either get the underlying container with the `GetContainer` extension or, preferably, do not actively resolve at all. Better let the container inject without the consumer knowing where stuff comes from.

Sidenote: the bootstrapper's still there. Being marked as obsolete does not mean "cannot be used".

Comment: Thanks. It is strange how this function is removed from the facade (IContainerProvider) as there could be a real case where consumer needs to deal with multiple instances of the type.

Comment: You can always have an array or an `IEnumerable` injected, if you need all the registered types.

Comment: Thats a good idea, however, it takes out the extensibility aspect. Imagine you are loading all the addins of an application. Addins (in form of DLLs) can be just dropped dynamically after compilation.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding somewhere, for injecting an array does exactly the same as `ResolveAll`. Where the registrations are done doesn't matter. Say `ModuleA` registers `ControllerA` and `ModuleB` registers `ControllerB` and some code gets `IController[]` injected, it will receive an instance of `ControllerA` and one of `ControllerB`, as if some code does `ResolveAll<IController>`

Comment: As soon as there is a need to add code which gets the IController[] injected, extensibility is lost. That code is now dependent on ControllerA and ControllerB. ResolveAll provides loose coupling.

Comment: No, not at all. `public MyService( IController[] controllers ) {...}` is dependent on `IController`, but has no idea about or dependency on neither `ControllerA` nor `ControllerB`. It will work if they aren't there but `ControllerC` is, or even if there's no implementation of `IController` at all.